# Reduce Image quality using php and imagejpeg

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I reduce the quality of an image using `PHP`? I've been trying it with this code:

```
function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) {
    $info = getimagesize($source_url);

    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);

    //save file
    imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);

    //return destination file
    return $destination_url;
}

if( isset( $_FILES['file'] ) ) :

    $wp_upload_directory = wp_upload_dir();  
    $path = $wp_upload_directory['basedir'].'/path';
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $tempPath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    $fullPath = $path . '/' . $fileName;

    $fileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

    $d = compress_image($tempPath, $fullPath, 0);

    if( file_exists( $d ) ) :

    $fullPath = make_unique( $d );

    $return = move_uploaded_file( $tempPath, $d );

    $fileName = str_replace( $path . '/', '', $d);

    die( $fileName );

    endif;
endif
```

But this doesn't work? Why?

Comment: Add relevant image processing library tag to the question and define what _this doesn't work_ actually mean, please.

Comment: what doesn't work ? your `compress_image` function ? the upload process (maybe `enctype="multipart/form-data` is missing from your html form). You should test every function output to see if all is ok (`imagejpeg` for example)

Comment: Yes the compress image function. I am also using AJAX to upload images. I am using GD Library for this one, and I cannot figure out why does this function is not working. Also, I check the GD Library and it was already installed.

Comment: I checked all of the functions that was used inside compress_image. I checked imagejpeg and it returns true. I don't really know why this is not working. :( still can't figure this out. pls. help. i added enctype on my html form,